# Swift Array<Set> How can I map and return true if the $0 set matches another set?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array arrCommands and in it there's a few different sets  -
[["play"], ["play message"], ["play message from"], etc.

I'm using speech recognition to get some user inputted commands, I have an array of the different commands (play, message) etc. and I build a set from the intersection of the array of the words spoken and my tags array.

So, if the user said, "Can you play the message please" I would be able to get ["play", "message"] from the spoken command. I then want to check the arrCommands and see if there's a match between this set and the ones it holds.

I tried doing this:

```
let isCommand = arrCommands.map { if setTags.isSubset(of: $0) { return true } }
```

But I get this error: **Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate**

But adding -> Bool set off a series of error messages. I am sure this is simple and I am just missing it but any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your statement:

```
let isCommand = arrCommands.map { if setTags.isSubset(of: $0) { return true } }
```

So, you `return true` when `setTags.isSubset(of: $0)`.

What happens when the condition is false? You don't have any other `return` statement. So when the condition is false, the closure returns `()` (also called `Void`).

To deduce the type returned by the closure, the compiler needs to find a type that is a supertype of both `Bool` and `Void`. There is no such type. The compiler gives up trying to find it and emits a not-very-helpful error message.

You could fix this by adding a second `return` statement:

```
let isCommand = arrCommands.map { if setTags.isSubset(of: $0) { return true } else { return false } }
```

But generally, `if x { return true } else { return false }` means exactly the same thing as `return x`. So simplify:

```
let isCommand = arrCommands.map { return setTags.isSubset(of: $0) }
```

Since there's only one statement in the closure, you can even omit the `return` keyword:

```
let isCommand = arrCommands.map { setTags.isSubset(of: $0) }
```

Comment: Thanks for breaking that down for me.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want:

```
let isCommand = arrCommands.contains { setTags.isSubset(of: $0) }
```

If this won't pass than you probably have a type mismatch somewhere.

Note that your closure:

```
{ if setTags.isSubset(of: $0) { return true } }
```

would return a `Bool` if the condition is `true` and it would return `Void` if the condition is `false`. The compiler won't be able to decide what the return type is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler suggests to use the syntax

```
arrCommands.map { item -> T in
    return ...
}
```

and replace `T` with the static (return) type.

Comment: The problem here is that there is **no** static return type for his closure. No such type exists.

Comment: Then the `map` function is not appropriate for that purpose. `T` is supposed to be the type the array is mapped to.